# Macbook Pro Touchbar and USB SuperDrive, shows that the disc is empty but it has a recorded video

Tags: usb, video, optical-drive, cd-burning

I am using a 2017 Macbook Pro laptop (with touchbar), using High Sierra 10.13.6.

I have several old discs with videos taken from many years ago (from around 1995!) and we can play these on a DVD player. I am trying to read the discs using a USB SuperDrive. Here is a visual of my setup:

[image]

(I put the USB in the SuperDrive, then connect the SuperDrive to an adapter that plugs into one of the 4 slots of the touchbar.)

I put in the disc, and feel some whirring sound on the discs. Then it shows me:

[image]

The other options are:

[image]

If I open in Finder, I see this:

[image]

I am not sure about what I should do at this point. It seems like my laptop cannot see any files. The discs do not look scratched or dirty. Does anyone have advice for troubleshooting? Or are these videos just too old to be used, or is this not the right usage of the USB SuperDrive (I have not used it before)?

Comment: Just to be clear. You have a DVD player and if you put these discs into the player *now* they play fine? I have CDR/DVD-Rs about the same age, sometimes they work sometimes not. Some computers they work in, some not. If it is an option try another computer (Mac or PC) or another drive.

Comment: Most external drives I have owned can be particular about owner recorded cd or dvd - some recording drives are better than others.